# Java vs JavaScript increment operator

Tags: java, javascript

In Java, if I do this

```
int value = 3;
int incr = value++;
```

incr is 4

but in JavaScript,

```
int value = 3;
int incr = value++;
```

incr is 3

in order for incr to be 4 in JS I have to do

```
int incr = ++value;
```

why is this?

Comment: If that happens to you in Java, your Java is broken. (And if your JavaScript environment accepts that code, then it's broken too.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not correct.

In Java, the following:

```
int value = 3;
int incr = value++;
```

... will leave you with:

```
value = 4;
incr = 3;
```

This is because value++ is a post-increment. This means that the value is incremented after it is used by the containing clause. So `incr` is set to `value`, then `value` is incremented.